# A Numerical Computing Library for C

Tags: numerical-computing

I’m looking for a good numerical computing library for C programming language.

Similar to LAPACK with good documentation would be very helpful.

Thanks & Regards,

Upul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly C (machine translation from Fortran), but you might find [clapack](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/) useful. You might also want to take a look at [ATLAS](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/). There are also quite a few implementations of BLAS in C -- enough that I'd have difficulty picking one to recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the GNU scientific library 
http://www.gnu.org/s/gsl/